# How to make button have a pop-up effect and border to have a white shadow when mouse hover above the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

***Functionality:***

The Button should have the following effect when user hover above the button:

- The Button should have a pop-up effect.
- The Button border should have white shadow effect.

***What has been done:***

I have made use of

```
img:hover{
            border-color: white;
        }
```

to try to get the effect of the a border shadow of white.

***Issue:***

I can't really seem to get the said effect. However, I was able to get the effect such as this :

```
img:hover{
            background-color: white;
        }
```

when user hover above the button.

Hence, how am I able to create the css such that when user hover above the button, it will create the said effect.

Thanks.

```css
img:hover {
  border-color: white;
}
#Button1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 310px;
  left: 1550px;
  outline: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button id="Button1" onclick="GreatLoveInSingapore()">
  <img src="lib/img/GreatLoveButton.png">
</button>
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by popup effect? (shall it shrink and get to normal size during click procesS?)

Comment: @DeepakYadav Popup effect- grow

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for but you can use something like `box-shadow` property to get similar effect. See **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/m2cnu42e/)**

Comment: @abhishekkannojia understood on the box shadow, but how do you make the button grow when you hover above it?

Comment: To make the button bigger you can add more `padding` I think it would be a better option than `height` or `width`

Comment: @NewToJS, I did exactly that under the hover part, to increase the width and height to the exact amount, but it kinda screw up the entire look and feel. what do you mean by padding

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to grow up your button you should use transfrom it allow you to scale your button

```css
div{
  margin: 50px 200px;
}
button{
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.7s;
}
img:hover{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMiabf0.jpg">
  </button>
</div>
```

EDIT: another way if you have img not text

```css
div.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1984c3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.1s;
}
a:hover{
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Hi Im a Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of padding....

```css
button{
    transition: padding 1s;
}
button:hover {
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px #888888;
padding:15px;
}
```

```html
<button><img src="#"/></button>
```

Transition is used to give the button an animated stretch and box-shadow for the pop-out effect. This is just a quick example mainly to focus on the padding.

I'm sure you can expand on this applying more styles to fit your needs.
Any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!